# PHP PDO Statement MySQL fail on query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having difficulty updating a table via PHP.
Using MySQL prompt or a client app the SQL command works fine, yet when I attempt it in PHP using PDO it fails.

I have taken out the '**desc**' field and the PHP script works. I think its getting confused with *ASC/DES*

```
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$sql = "UPDATE Menu SET name=:name, desc=:desc WHERE id = :id"

$st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );


$st->bindValue( ":id",  $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$st->bindValue( ":name", $this->name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$st->bindValue( ":desc", $this->name,  PDO::PARAM_STR );


$b = $st->execute();
```

Im pretty sure its just confused from field name to SQL language construct but is there a way of telling the PDO object/prepared statement that desc is a field name ?

i.e something linke

```
(this does not work by the way)
    $sql = "UPDATE Menu SET name=:name, \'desc\'=:desc WHERE id=:id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `id = 1`, not `id = :id`

You can't bind to a parameter that doesn't exist.

Also `DESC` is a reserved word, you cannot use it without quoting it with backticks.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `Menu` SET `name`=:name, `desc`=:desc WHERE `id`=:id"
```

Comment: oops thanks, better fix the example, btw:this is not my actual code

Comment: Everytime I see this online I thought it was a single quote!! now this makes sense. cheers thankyou so much. All working now

Comment: Im new to StackOverflow, but Im learning so much here. Thanks Leigh